# Problems using multiple PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

Ok, I have been fighting this too long, time to ask for help. HELP!!!

I'm deploying an indipendent jar maven project that will be used as dependency into other projects.
I need that this jar loads its own properties file ("versione.properties" released inside the jar) when the application that will use it, will start up but I want that the application doesn't care about it. This should be in charge on the lib.
I want that who will use this lib, will have just to

1. include the right dependency inside his pom.xml
2. add `<import resource="classpath*:*-context.xml" />` inside his spring app-context.xml to be sure to include also the lib-context.xml during the spring-context initialization

For this reason, the jar has its own spring *lib-context.xml* file as the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.eng.inps.comppsr" />

<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer2" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:versione.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="version" class="it.eng.inps.comppsr.util.Versione">
    <property name="buildVersion" value="${comppsrutil.build.version}"/>
    <property name="buildDate" value="${comppsrutil.build.timestamp}"/>
</bean>
```

As you can immagine, "versione.properties" file contains *comppsrutil.build.version* and *comppsrutil.build.timestamp*.
During my tests, I've tried also `<value>classpath*:versione.properties</value>`, `<value>classpath:/versione.properties</value>` and `<value>classpath:*/versione.properties</value>` but with no luck.

This library is used by a web-service application (a war inside an ear file) and this application has got its own spring *app-context.xml* that loads it own properties file as described by the following code snippet

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" depends-on="lookupPropertiesInitializer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:///#{lookupPropertiesInitializer.pathToProperties}</value>
            <value>classpath*:version.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="it.eng.inps.util, it.eng.inps.comppsr" />

<import resource="classpath*:*-context.xml" />
```

When I start the application (it runs inside JBoss EAP 7.3), I get this error:
*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'comppsrutil.build.version' in value "${comppsrutil.build.version}"*

So, it seems that something goes wrong within the lib initialization.
If I rename the "versione.properties" file in "version.properties" (so with the same name used by the app properties file), this error desappear, I think, because it is loaded by the application *PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer*, so the lib property file is well located.
For this reason I think that the bean *propertyPlaceholderConfigurer2* defined inside lib-context.xml, doesn't work as I expected but I didn't understand why.

Does anyone give me any tips?

Comment: For all used `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` set the `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to `true` else the first one to run will fail. I would also strongly suggest **not** to use things like this as this will actually make things harder instead of easier. What you should do is create an `@Configuration` class add an `@PropertySource` on there so that the file will be loaded. That way there will be only a singel placeholder configurer which is far less error prone.

Comment: Another note is that you are using the old(er) `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as you state in your question.

Comment: Thanks.
Finally I solved and following your suggestion, I've converted my code into a @Configuration class.
In this way, as you said, I let just one PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in the app-context.xml file.

Comment: You should use a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` **not** a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Or even better just use `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:your-properties.properties" />`. Which will automatically construct the proper configurer.